# How do I view VLAN tagged packets with any ID?

Tags: networking, vlan, tshark

I'm trying to sniff with tshark on debian and I want to see all the traffic, but I'm missing the VLAN traffic.

I can manually configure the interface to add VLAN 10 to eth0 interface and then query either:

```
# tshark -i eth0 -w /home/debian/capture/testcapture8.pcap
[NO PACKETS]

# vconfig add eth0 10
# tshark -i eth0 -w /home/debian/capture/testcapture8.pcap
[ALL PACKETS on VLAN 10 and on eth0]

# vconfig rem eth0.10
# vconfig add eth0 20
# tshark -i eth0 -w /home/debian/capture/testcapture8.pcap
[NO PACKETS]
```

So I'm able to see the VLAN tagged packets only with vconfig using that specific VLAN ID. How can I see all packets without knowing the VLAN ID to add on vconfig?

Comment: is your switch filtering packets for vlan 10 & 20 before your linux box sees them?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tshark -i eth0.10 -w /home/debian/capture/testcapture8.pcap` to capture packets for VLAN 10.

From: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/VLAN

(bold emphasis added by me)

> [...]
>
> Linux
>
> To enable VLAN tagging, you need two things: the vlan rpm (e.g.,
>   vlan-1.8-23) and the 8021q kernel module. Once installed, the vconfig
>   command can be used to create VLAN interfaces on an existing physical
>   device. For more info, see the vconfig(8) man page.
>
> After your VLAN interfaces are set up and traffic is flowing, you can
>   run Wireshark and capture on the VLAN interface of your choice (e.g.,
>   eth0.100 for VLAN 100) or on the underlying physical interface (e.g.,
>   eth0). If you choose the former, you will only see frames destined for
>   that VLAN; **if you choose the latter, you may see all frames or you may
>   see only untagged frames** (if there are any). **It depends on the NIC,
>   the NIC firmware, the driver, and the alignment of the moon and
>   planets.** (A table enumerating the behaviors of various adapters,
>   firmware versions, and drivers might be useful. -Guy Harris)
>
> If you are capturing on the host system where the VLANs are
>   configured, you will probably not see the VLAN tags in the captured
>   frames -- even if you capture on the physical device. The driver is
>   stripping the tags before the pcap library sees them. See the tech
>   note from Intel mentioned in the Windows section below. (Do Linux
>   drivers support getting VLAN tags, perhaps with a driver configuration
>   option or other option, in the same way that the Intel Windows driver
>   does? -Guy Harris) (e100 driver works great on 2.4.26 - Jaap Keuter)

Also worth reading: https://wiki.wireshark.org/VLAN